How to troubleshoot why a USB volume knob stops working?
On my Windows 10 desktop PC, a generic USB volume knob (rotary encoder, push to mute/unmute) stops working after a while:  its blue LED stays lit, but Windows no longer changes its volume or mutes/unmutes.  Plugging it into a different USB port makes it work again, but only sometimes, and then for a few seconds or a few days.
This happens with several knobs from random vendors from Newegg.  All work fine on a different Win10 PC, and on an Ubuntu PC, so the fault isn't likely to be in the knobs.  (Also, the "Cherry Stream TKL" keyboard's -/mute/+ keys continue to work.)
This isn't nearly enough info to make the knob reliable again, of course.
But how can I isolate the fault?  Might an error message be getting written to a log file somewhere?  Can I trace how far the signal from the knob reaches into Windows' innards?  (Don't tell me to reinstall Windows and then install one app at a time, waiting a few days after each step to confirm that the knob's still working.)

Have you updated all device firmware and drivers?

Yes, Device Manager says drivers are up to date for all USB gizmos and for all entries under Firmware.

So you have one Win PC that has this issue with a "USB volume knob", and another Win PC that does not. One simple (but tedious) "trouble shooting" step to perform is a thorough comparison of the driver(s) used by the device and all the assigned attributes/properties.

Do not trust Windows regarding your drivers: It is fine when things are working OK, but they are not. Also, I asked about firmwares, and Windows does a less good job keeping those up to date. Go to the manufacturer support pages, download the latest available firmwares and drivers, particularly for your mainboard and other devices surrounding the USB systems, and install those.
